# Linq DataContext still retrieve "Deleted" object

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm working with a grid bound to Linq Data "Object list".

The grid behave in a "disconnected fashion" it means that when I edit or suppress a line the change is not immediately submitted to the database. There is a separate "save" button that is to be clicked after all changes are made to call the DataContext.SubmitChanges method.

The problem is when i delete a line in the grid, the deleteonsubmit method is well called, but when i rebind the grid just after, the line is still here !

I need a behavior like with Datatables where the lines in the Deleted state are not displayed when the datatable is bound to a grid. Is this possible ?

### Addendum

There is not a lot of code, because the GridView use it's automatic behavior (AutoGenerateColumns, AutoGenerateEditButton etc)

Here is the code I use to Delete the Object

```
<DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete)> _
Public Sub Supprimer(ByVal code As Integer)
    Dim ctx = getDataContext()

    Dim leGerant = (From g In ctx.Gerant Where g.CODE = code).FirstOrDefault
    ctx.Gerant.DeleteOnSubmit(leGerant)

    End Sub
```

Here is the code I use to select objects

```
    <DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)> _
    Public Function Selectionner()
        Dim ctx = getDataContext()

        Return From g In ctx.Gerant
    End Function
```

@magnus

You didn't understand my problem. I do call SubmitChanges when the save button is clicked, and the changes take effects well. The problem is not here.

The problem is when i delete a line in the grid, the deleteonsubmit method is well called, but when i rebind the grid just after, the line is still here ! Normally the deleted object shouldn't appear as a line in the GridView, even if I have not submit my changes to the database yet.

Comment: Well it depends on your code... which you have not shown us...

Comment: Post some code so that it may clear your query.

Comment: You have to call `ctx.SubmitChanges()` for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

`DeleteOnSubmit` does not 'delete' the item. It marks it as to be deleted on the next submit.

You need to add the submit line so it becomes:

```
Dim ctx = getDataContext()
Dim leGerant = (From g In ctx.Gerant Where g.CODE = code).FirstOrDefault    
ctx.Gerant.DeleteOnSubmit(leGerant)
ctx.SubmitChanges()
```

**Edit:** Assuming the ctx is the same instance in both your calls you could try

```
<DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)> _
Public Function Selectionner()
    Dim ctx = getDataContext()

    Dim deleted = ctx.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Deleted).OfType<Gerant>();

    Return (From g In ctx.Gerant).Except(deleted);
End Function
```

This is untested so I am unsure if it will work but it seems to compile.

Comment: OK, do you mean that objects marked to be deleted continue always to be retrieved, util I submit the changes to the database ?!

Comment: If yes, a solution for me, is to keep in memory a list of code of deleted objects, and exclude them from the select request.

Comment: @Kernel999 What I mean is that until the `SubmitChanges` is called, the Values are still in the database. Your call of `Return From g In ctx.Gerant` will therefore continue to retrieve them.

Comment: @Kernel999 Added a possible workaround if the ctx is the same instance.

Comment: The ctx is the same instance, and according to my knowledge, if I execute "Return From g In ctx.Gerant" several times with the same DataContext, it will access the DB just the first time, the other times it use the same data returned by the first request.

Comment: Thank you for this instruction, i didn't know that. ctx.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Deleted).OfType<Gerant>();